# ffmpeg concat always return error `Invalid data found when processing input`

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I think I did it right by following the guide on [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) but it didn't work

[Demo file](https://mega.nz/file/NlIGELxZ#iOb1eci8bK89ReFa3HU3ezDIPp-tkPz5xwC1MfStUCQ)

The 1.mp4 and 2.mp4 are cut from the same video so they have the same encoding

Setup:
[image: demo]

```
@echo off
@cd/d %~dp0
(for %%i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%%i') > Concat.txt
ffmpeg  -i Concat.txt  -f concat  -safe 0  -c copy  output_concat.mp4
pause
```

Result:
[image: result]

```
  ffmpeg version 2021-12-12-git-996b13fac4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100
  libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 20.100 /  8. 20.100
  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Concat.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think I uploaded the demo with everything ready, all you need is double click on `Test.bat`

Comment: It might be a problem with utf encoding. Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642227/how-do-i-resolve-ffmpeg-concat-command-error-unknown-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642227/how-do-i-resolve-ffmpeg-concat-command-error-unknown-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f concat` is the switch that is supposed to specify the "demuxer", so it needs to be placed before `-i Concat.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized that the order matters